# Troubleshooting "syntax error, unexpected ‘;’"

Tags: php, wordpress, syntax-error

```
<?php  
  $dbhost = "localhost";
  $dbuser = "test";
  $dbpass = "testpass";
  $dbname = "testdb";

  foreach((get_the_category('orderby=ID&order=ASC')) as $childcat)
  {
    if (cat_is_ancestor_of(8, $childcat))
    {
      echo $childcat->cat_ID . ;
    }
  }
?></span>
</ul>
```

This is the code above I have in php, Its displaying values correctly but I am getting this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ‘;’  at line 20.

What I am doing wrong here? Is there any syntax issue here? Its displaying the values correctly but also displaying this error.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies but if I do echo $childcat->cat_ID ; it does not display any values for Categories from database. If I include . at end it displays the categories correctly with this error, any ideas?

Comment: Does that ID happen to be 0 or 1?

Comment: Sorry I am a newbie to php. But I tried print_r($childcat);  instead of echo command and it did not display anything. I also tried to change 0 and 1 it does not display anything. --I changed ID to 1 in if command above if (cat_is_ancestor_of(1, $childcat)) , it still displayed same values. I am just following this post: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-display-the-child-category-of-a-specific-parent-category

Comment: I think that syntax never populate anything, I had wrong values in db. I am not using this syntax anymore , I have new code below I am using which is pulling from my tables in database and throwing this error now: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource. <ul> <?php $dbhost = "localhost";     $dbuser = "test";$dbpass = "testdb";$dbname = "dbtest";     $CategoryID="1";
$query = "SELECT * FROM 'subcategory' WHERE 'categoryid'= '".$CategoryID."'"; 
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($cat=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "$cat";
}
?></ul>  can someone help please?

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming this is line 20:

```
echo $childcat->cat_ID . ;
```

You're missing a string to append to. If you don't want to append a string, don't use the `.` operator.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $childcat->cat_ID . ;
```

You have a trailing period there.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is this line:

`echo $childcat->cat_ID . ;`

The period (dot) is the concatenation operator in PHP, so the preprocessor is expecting you to concatenate something but is getting an end-of-statement (;) instead.

Comment: if I do echo $childcat->cat_ID ; it does not display any values. If I include . it displays the categories correctly, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There is error in your code.

Change

```
echo $childcat->cat_ID . ;
```

to

```
echo $childcat->cat_ID ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using var_dump($childcat); exit; before line 20 to see what $childcat contains, it will always returns something. If a variable is empty var_dump returns null, so try it out and see. Also do a var_dump on $childcat->cat_ID to check its value. The line 20 with '.' operator is wrong, and you must find out why are you getting output by appending the concatenation operator at the end, this can be done by checking variables through var_dump and then proceeding forward according to the results you get.